# Viewing posts that you've edited, but were later deleted or merged?

Tags: feature-request, editing

I noticed that I lost four points of reputation earlier, and the number of posts I've edited was also reduced by two. Is there any way for me to tell which of the posts I edited were merged or deleted? They don't seem to appear in my profile any more, that I can tell.

I found in another similar question that users with more than 10,000 reputation can see deleted posts, but I think it would be useful for users of any reputation to be able to see the deleted posts that they've successfully edited.

It could be a good learning experience to go back and review a post I've edited, but happened to be subsequently deleted. Rather than edit such posts in the first place, it seems like it would be more appropriate to flag them immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had edited these two posts ([1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/292003/),[2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/292215/)) which were later closed and subsequently deleted. I'm afraid there's no way for you to see them before you get 10k rep, but your edit was fine in case you were wondering.

What you're asking for is very unlikely to be implemented since it would require SE to change the rules and allow users with less than 10k rep to see deleted posts. I also, frankly, don't really see the point. You don't have much to learn from such posts, they were just deleted. I suggest you just shrig it off and go on posting good content and suggesting good edits. You'll get to 10k in no time!

Comment: Fair enough. I didn't consider that a user might have deleted his own post (not that this is necessarily what happened with those two edits).